# Setting the dropdown for the action bar button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to display a `Drop down` that contain the items from Array List when click on button on action bar.

Is there any good practice/tutorial to accomplish this?

Comment: I want add the data from DB in list form when I tapped on actionbar button

Answer (score 0):

i think you can somthink like that put the arraylist as the spinner database

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
//adapter helps to add data to spinner.
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,user_spinner_string);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```